# how map model to knockout

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

How I can map array from my model to knockout viewModel?

I have tried this:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
   @model Hotel.Web.Controllers.FoodOrderModelView

   <table class="table table-responsive table-hover" data-bind="foreach: Items">
     <tr class="row">
       <td>
        <label data-bind="text: $data"></label>
        <label data-bind="text: Name"></label>
       </td>
     </tr>                            
  </table>

    <script>        
        function viewModel() {
            self = this;
            self.Items = ko.observableArray([]);
            var jsonModel = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.LunchItems, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling  = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore}));
            console.log(jsonModel);
            var mvcModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonModel,{}, self);
            self.Items(mvcModel);
            console.log(self.Items);
        };

        $(function () { 
            var myViewModel = new viewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);   
        });
    </script>
```

I get right JSON and strange message.

On console I get this log:

why I can't see mvcModel?

```
1. [Object, Object, ...]
0:
Object Count: 0
Name: " item"
   ...
2. function observable() {
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            // Write

            // Ignore writes if the value hasn't changed
            if (observable.isDifferent(observable[observableL…
```

**EDITED:**

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "LunchOrderItemId": 0,
        "FoodItem": {
            "LunchItemID": 1,
            "Name": " item",
            "Price": 196,
            "Description": " item description",
            "Category": 2,
            "File": null,
            "FileId": 1
        },
        "FoodItemId": 0,
        "Count": 0
    },
    {
        "LunchOrderItemId": 0,
        "FoodItem": {
            "LunchItemID": 2,
            "Name": "1 item",
            "Price": 29,
            "Description": "1 item description",
            "Category": 2,
            "File": null,
            "FileId": null
        },
        "FoodItemId": 0,
        "Count": 0
    },
    {
        "LunchOrderItemId": 0,
        "FoodItem": {
            "LunchItemID": 3,
            "Name": "2 item",
            "Price": 19,
            "Description": "2 item description",
            "Category": 2,
            "File": null,
            "FileId": null
        },
        "FoodItemId": 0,
        "Count": 0
    }
]
```

Here fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/ez358nv6/

Comment: Why would you think the console output you get is wrong? Looks okayish at first sight to me?

Comment: In any case, if you want our help, you need to help us reproduce the issue. Try to eliminate server side as a potential cause and provide us with a fully client side repro (i.e. by inlining the result of that `@Html.Raw` call in the SO question).

Comment: @Jeroen, I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all sorts of problems in your code, most notably:

- You're both *saving* the result from `fromJS` as well as supplying `self` as the third argument (i.e. the update target). From what I see the latter should suffice.
- You're not declaring `self` properly as a `var`.
- Your JSON *is* an array, but if you want to use `fromJS` to apply it to `self` as a target, the JSON should be an object with an `Items` property.
- Your view assumes all of the `Items` have a `Name` property, but according to your own JSON that's nested one level deeper.

By the way, you should have `Items` as a property on the thing going into `fromJS`. You can either fix that on the c# side, or you can hack around it as below in my example.

With those things fixed, here's a slightly improved code sample to work with:

```js
// Abbreviated
var rawJson = [
    {
      "LunchOrderItemId": 0,
      "FoodItem": {
        "LunchItemID": 1,
        "Name": " item"
      }
    },
    {
      "LunchOrderItemId": 0,
      "FoodItem": {
        "LunchItemID": 2,
        "Name": "1 item"
      }
    }
];

function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.Items = ko.observableArray([]);
  var jsonModel = { Items: rawJson };
  ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonModel, {}, self);
};

var myViewModel = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

```css
label { padding: 4px; border: 1px solid gray; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<table data-bind="foreach: Items">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label data-bind="text: LunchOrderItemId"></label>
      <label data-bind="text: FoodItem.Name"></label>
    </td>
  </tr>                            
</table>
```

Comment: maybe it doesn't works because the model of the razor view is a````IEnumerable````.

Comment: That wouldn't matter much. It would be trivial to either fix that on the c# side, as well as fixing that on the view side as OP's using `Html.Raw` anyways. Guess I can improve my answer slightly to suggest a solution, will do so.

Comment: @Jeroen, thanks for your answer, a have spent all day to solve this problem. As I can see I can't map array to viewModel

Comment: @ArtemShaban sure you can, just see my answer.

Comment: @ArtemShaban My answer is one way to solve it, but Joel's right that the other answer (after last edits) shows a fine way to do things too. - (That answer also differs from mine because it assumes the json is available as a json-string and not as a js object, probably because you've changed from one to the other in edits to the question... but that's just a detail IMO)

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse the JSON to JS object first with `JSON.parse(jsonModel)`,
See how to parse the json to js object in the snippet:

```js
var jsonModel = '[{"LunchOrderItemId":0,"FoodItem":{"LunchItemID":1,"Name":" item","Price":196.00,"Description":" item description","Category":2,"File":null,"FileId":1},"FoodItemId":0,"Count":0},{"LunchOrderItemId":0,"FoodItem":{"LunchItemID":2,"Name":"1 item","Price":29.00,"Description":"1 item description","Category":2,"File":null,"FileId":null},"FoodItemId":0,"Count":0},{"LunchOrderItemId":0,"FoodItem":{"LunchItemID":3,"Name":"2 item","Price":19.00,"Description":"2 item description","Category":2,"File":null,"FileId":null},"FoodItemId":0,"Count":0}]';

function viewModel() {
          self = this;
          self.Items = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
          ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON.parse(jsonModel),self.Items);                  
          console.log(self.Items());
        };

        $(function() {
          var myViewModel = new viewModel();
          ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-responsive table-hover" data-bind="foreach: Items">
  <tr class="row">
    <td>
      <label data-bind="text: $data.FoodItem.Name"></label>
      <label data-bind="text: $data.FoodItem.Description"></label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> But this is a workaround because you are using JSON.Net to Serialize the model and it return a JSON string, you can use this to raw your model `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` and it will be the JS object from  the JSON.